# How can I implement dynamic wait in it?

Tags: dynamic, wait

```
class getPageObj:
    @staticmethod
    def getIDByLabel(driver, form_type, label_name):
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\chromedriver.exe")
        if label_name.find("[") == -1:
            xpath_exp = "//label[text()='"+label_name+"'][1]"
        else:
            label_sub_str = label_name[:label_name.find("[")]
            label_indx_str = label_name[label_name.find("["):label_name.find("]") + 1]
            xpath_exp = "//label[text()='" + label_sub_str + "']"+label_indx_str

        if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_exp)) > 0:
            if form_type == "Form":
                id=getPageObj()
                attr_id = id.getAttrValueByXPath(driver, xpath_exp, "for")
                return attr_id
            else:
                id=getPageObj()
                attr_id = id.getAttrValueByXPath(driver, xpath_exp, "for")
                return attr_id
```

Comment: You need to tag this correctly with the language of your code so that it will be visible to a much wider audience. Before you do that, you need to spend a little time writing a more specific question and, ideally, show what you've tried and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I need to add custom wait in it